# add to numpy string array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following two numpy arrays:

```
a1
array(['T', 'T', 'T', ..., 'G', 'A', 'A'], dtype=object)

a2
array(['A', 'G', 'C', ..., 'A', 'T', 'G'], dtype=object)
```

I want to add each element from the two arrays. The following command works:

```
s = a1 + a2
s
array(['TA', 'TG', 'TC', ..., 'GA', 'AT', 'AG'], dtype=object)
```

But I get an error when trying to use `numpy.char.add`:

```
np.char.add(a1, a2)

TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: if you don't want to use numpy.char.add, you can either use a classic for loop and zip, or use the map function.

Comment: `np.add(a1,a2)` works the same as `a1+a2`.  This uses the `add` method of each object.  `np.char` functions apply string methods to numpy char dtypes.  The result is similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your types are `object` try setting it to `str` and it'll work:

```
import numpy as np

a1=np.array(['T', 'T', 'T', ..., 'G', 'A', 'A'], dtype=str)

a2=np.array(['A', 'G', 'C', ..., 'A', 'T', 'G'], dtype=str)

print(np.char.add(a1, a2))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't want to change your dataType use [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)

`print np.asarray([x[0]+x[1] for x in zip(a1,a2)])`

2. Change your datatypes to str and use

   `print np.char.add(a1, a2)`